# SED keep pattern in \1 for next block/command

Tags: sed

I want match a pattern, but replace something else with the matched pattern.

```
pattern1    X1 X2 X3
pattern2    X4 X5
...
```

should be transformed into

```
pattern1-1
pattern1-2
pattern1-3

pattern2-4
pattern2-5

...
```

I can't just replace 'X' because it is multiple times in a row.

I tried `sed -r '/(pattern[0-9])/ { s/X/\n\1/g; }'`
but this will give me an `` invalid reference \1 on `s `` error.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: With `perl`: `perl -pe 's{^(pattern\d+)((?:\s+X\d+)*)$}{ $res=join("\n$1-", split(/\s+X/,$2));$res=~s/^\n//r}ge' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/8fR6yR).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(\S+)\s+X(\S+)/\1-\2\n\1/;/-/!s/.*//;P;D' file
```

Use pattern matching to match the first field and another beginning with `X`. Manipulate to the desired result and then append a newline and the first field again. Print/delete upto and including the first newline and if a line does not match delete, its contents i.e. print a blank line.

If the blank line is not required, use:

```
sed -E 's/(\S+)\s+X(\S+)/\1-\2\n\1/;/-/P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. Should be easy in `awk` IMHO.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="-"}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$i);print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk code from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN block for this code from here.
  OFS="-"                    ##Setting OFS as - here.
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){        ##Starting for loop from i=2 to till value of NF here.
    sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$i)     ##Substituting everything apart from digits in current field with NULL.
    print $1,$i              ##Printing first field and edited value of current field.
  }
}
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop manually until a pattern match is found.

```
sed '
    : loop
    # match the first line
    # ex. replace:
    #   pattern1 X1 X2 X3
    # for two lines:
    #   pattern1 X1 X2
    #   pattern1-3
    s/\(pattern[0-9]\)\( *[^\n]*\)X\([0-9]\)/\1\2\n\1-\3/
    # if the last s command was successfull, branch to loop
    t loop
    # remove first line
    # the "pattern1" will be left
    s/[^\n]*\n//
'
```

The following script:

```
cat <<EOF |
pattern1    X1 X2 X3
pattern2    X4 X5
EOF
sed ':a;s/\(pattern[0-9]\)\( *[^\n]*\)X\([0-9]\)/\1\2\n\1-\3/;ta;s/[^\n]*\n//'
```

[on repl outputs](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/StarchySaddlebrownSystems):

```
pattern1-1
pattern1-2
pattern1-3
pattern2-4
pattern2-5
```

If you need that newline between `pattern1` and `pattern2` you could add `s/$/\n/` on the end of the script.